# jQuery: How to reset multiple dropdowns after they have been cloned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, clone, dynamic-forms

At the moment my code  clones 3 dropdowns everytime you click the add button.

I managed to get it to copy the row exactly because before, the first dropdown would reset by itself but the other two would not so I was just wondering how to reset all 3 dropdowns?

It is easiest to see in this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jydqK/7/

So, if you change the first dropdown to `agent` and then click the + you will see the second row appears duplicated whereas I would like it to reset to `tags`, `operands` and `values`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use removeAttr to remove `selected` attribute and then fire a change() event.

In your case:

```
dropdownclone.find('select.tags option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
dropdownclone.find('select.tags option:first').attr('selected','selected');
dropdownclone.find('select.tags').trigger('change');
```

Modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZF3mc/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want the duplicated row of selects to reset their values.

In this case you can just remove this:

```
dropdownclone.find('select').each(function(index, item) {
 //set new select to value of old select
$(item).val( $dropdownSelects.eq(index).val() );
});
```

and replace it with:

```
dropdownclone.find('option').attr('selected', false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Find all dropdowns in your clone. For each dropdown, check every option tags for a selected attribute and remove it. Something like this:

```
clone.find('select').each(function() {
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
    });
});
```

Or better yet, find only the selected option tags using :selected filter before removing.